# .Net Runtime: FileNotFoundException Program.Main..cctor()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, filenotfoundexception

I am receiving this `FileNotFoundException` and am curious what the cause is.

```
.Net Runtime
---------------------------------------------------------------------
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-08-24T14:45:09.382117400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>820</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>Sarah-VPC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Application: Jobfish.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException at Jobfish.Program..cctor() Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException at Jobfish.Program.Main(System.String[])</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Here is a snipit from the Event Viewer general view.

```
Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException
   at Jobfish.Program..cctor()

Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
   at Jobfish.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Here are the details:

Everything works fine on my development desktop. I receive this error message on my Windows 10 64-bit VirtualBox PC.

The last time that I checked the app in the VirtualBox environment was with Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2015. Everything was fine. I updated to VS2017 and Windows 10 (latest) and I get the exception above.

I never receive my `MessageBox.Show()` debug statement at the `Program.Main()` entry point.

I looked over the references and they look fine, but then again, we are talking the entry point to the WinForm application, so right at the start. Also, the error is with .NetRuntime.

The target is with 4.5.1 and Windows 10 ships with 4.7.

I tried adding in `.Net Framework v2/3.5` from the `Add Windows Features` in `Programs and Features` control panel applet, no go. I also tried adding in the VS C++ Runtime 64 and X86 for VS2012, VS2015, and VS2017, also no go. I saw that recommended in a google search.

**Obviously**, the problem is that Windows cannot find something in space between main() and Program.Main(), which is in the startup code.

I did "upgrade" my application, so maybe an upgrade issue. I just tried a clean newly created X64 WinForm project and that comes up, so some difference.

The obvious way forward is to start adding things to the clean project one at a time and see when things break. Also doing the same thing between the two project files.

I was hoping that someone might know something, as this issue is VS2015/Win81 to VS2017Win10 related.

Is there a nice way to get more information? Event Viewer is nice, but not very helpful.

I tried copying over the RemoteDebuger files and starting the Remote Debugger on the Virtual Box, but VS2017 cannot find the remote system, so some IP/VBx issue. I tried installing .Net Framework 4.5, but was told that I already have it.

Google and SO posts did not seem very helpful, even when looking up `..cctor()` although the specific error is `TypeInitializationException` on 'System.String[]`, which is a very basic .Net thing, so almost the problem would seem to me to be that the applicable version of .Net is not installed, I have that with 4.7. Heck, as I said I attempted to install 4.5.1 using the offline installer, but obviously that failed, as 4.7 includes earlier versions of 4.X.

I ran the steps [outlined](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/125e76cc-dc83-436c-8502-9b3e60cfb5d5/net-framework-version-v4030319-description-the-process-was-terminated-due-to-an-unhandled?forum=netfxsetup) against 4.5.1, 4.5, 4.0, and 2.0 for the hell of it and all was fine. I expected as much on a new install of Windows.

Thoughts?

Comment: Run fuslogvw.exe, if it's a `TypeInitializationException` I would suspect that an assembly dependency didn't load for some reason.

Comment: What file do you load in your main constructor? Is it still exist in your new virtual box enviornment?

Comment: @GhostTW Hmm. You are right. The main constructor is what throws things, must be. Here is the line: `[STAThread]public static void Main(String[] args)`. My `TypeInitializationException` is on String[] and my constructor has `String[]`. That might be why the newly created project was fine. Thank you, another clue.

Comment: @code4life I copied the file to the virtual PC and nothing happens either from the admin command prompt or running via right-click run-as-admin. I even tried running with the /? and /help option from the command prompt and nothing. Task Manager nor the system tray show anything either, so maybe there is a dependency on a file or something for `fuglogvw.exe` to run.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when installing a new service, which looked like it was due to .Net Runtime or about directory permissions or service user permissions with the `IO.FileLoadException` and the `TypeInitializationException`:

[image]

The problem was actually not about any of that. The problem was to do with the version of an underlying `log4net.dll` that my service was trying to use to write a log. The service had been built with an older `Nuget` version.

I also had similar services running on the same box without the problem because they were built using the later version of `log4net.dll`.

When I added a more recent version of that `dll` the problem resolved.

Comment: How did you discover the root cause of your problem? The exception is so non-informative....

Comment: From the exception info which tells me that the method that went wrong was a type initialization in a `Logs.Enter()` method. That's my own method so I recognised it.